# Upload failed to publish android .aab extension file in google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

When I am publishing **.aab (Android App Bundle)** extension file in google play console then it showing me error i.e. **Upload failed
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your app bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again**

I search regarding this topic solution and I get also bt didnt work for me. like : **1. clean, rebuild and again generate signed bundle.
2. change the location for generate signed bundle.
3. delete the generated file when created at the generate signed bundle time.**

and many more. But didnt work anything.

Comment: Did you change the signing configuration when you built the App Bundle or are you signing with the same key as you were signing your previous APKs? When enrolling in App Signing by Play, did you choose to create a separate upload key?

Comment: Yes I changed whole configuration compare to previous one

Comment: Do you mean "Yes" for all my questions? If so, you should sign your App Bundle with the upload key, i.e. use the keystore you created when creating this upload key. You can go to the "App Signing" page in the Play Console to look at the certificate digest of the upload key and compare that with the digests of the key in the keystore to see if they match.

Comment: But when I open the keystore.jsk in notepad then it showing in the encrypted word. From that I can't understand it.

Comment: You need to use `keytool` to read a keystore. Search for how to print certificate from a keystore on Google. You'll need to know the alias and password from the key in the keystore.